# How to find the domain interval of an inverse function

Tags: calculus, functions

I am taking an online calc 2 class and have come across something that I am struggling to understand how to do. Unfortunately, I am not teaching myself correctly and I have been unable to meet with anyone that can help me alas I have nowhere else to turn.

My problem lies within understanding how to solve problems like the following:
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{6}(x−3), 4≤x≤8$$
The domain of $f^{-1}$ is the interval $[A,B]$ where $A=$(solve for this) and where $B=$(solve for this).

Comment: The domain of $f^{-1}$ is the same as the image of $f$. Does that help?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the image of $f$ exactly.

Comment: The image of $f$ is the collection of values that $f$ takes.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, lets go through some terminology first.

Given a function $f$, the **domain** of $f$ is the collection of things that you can plug into $f$. In your example, the domain is given explicitly as the $x$ between $4$ and $8$ (i.e. $4 \leq x \leq 8$).

The **range** of a function is the collection of all values of $f$. For instance the range of $\sin x$ (with domain $\mathbb{R}$) is $[-1,1]$. The range of $x^2$ (on the same domain) is all non-negative reals.

The **inverse function** $f^{-1}$ is the function which "undoes" the work of $f$: Formally $f(f^{-1}(y)) = y$ and $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$ for all $y$ in the domain of $f^{-1}$ and all $x$ in the domain of $f$. *If $f^{-1}$ exists*, then the domain and range of $f^{-1}$ are precisely the range and domain of $f$, respectively.

So, to find the domain of $f^{-1}$ we need only find the range of $f$. In general, this is a very hard problem and there is no general method that works in all cases. However with the $f(x) = \frac{1}{6}(x-3)$ for $4 \leq x \leq 8$, we can find the range explicitly.

Firstly, observe that $f$ is increasing. That means the smallest value of $f(x)$ occurs when $x$ is smallest, and the biggest value occurs when $x$ is biggest. That means that anything, $y$, in the range of $f$ has to satisfy $f(4) \leq y \leq f(8)$. Now, do we get every value inbetween, or do we miss some? If you know the Intermediate Value Theorem, you can appeal to that to show that every number between $f(4)$ and $f(8)$ is in the range of $f$ (because $f$ is continuous). If you don't know this theorem, you can try solving the equation $f(x) = y$ and see what happens.

In either case you get that the range of $f$ is of the form $[f(4),f(8)]$ and you can do the arithmetic.

Comment: I appreciate your attempt to help, but I have already gone through these steps in the comments of the previous answer. Unless you see a fault in the thinking there, I am at a loss.

Comment: I suggest you read the relevant chapter of the book again, as, you appeared to be unfamiliar with the standard terminology.

Comment: The only terminology that you had used that I was unfamiliar with was "image". But thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 3):

As $f$ is increasing, $f^{-1}$ is too. Furthermore, the domain of  $f^{-1}$  is the range of $f$, and, as $f$ is continuous, this range is the closed interval with bounds:
$$A=f(4), \quad B=f(8).$$

Comment: So what you are saying is that $A=\frac{1}{6}(4-3)=\frac{1}{6}$ and $B=\frac{1}{6}(8-3)=\frac{5}{6}$? What I typed doesn't appear to be correct according to the back of my book.

Comment: Yes. Naturally this is true because $f$  is increasing and continuous. If it were decreasing, you would have to exchange the bounds, and if $f$ were  non-monotonic, it wouldn't be one-to-one, so $f^{-1}$ wouldn't exist.

Comment: After assuming the BOB was wrong in this instance I decided to try it with my online homework for a different problem using your method. It still comes up with an incorrect answer for both $A$ and $B$. I'm at a loss.

Comment: Who's BOB? I don't speak Acronym very fluently… More seriously, could you give another example of problem with an incorrect answer? It might help understand where and why there is a problem.

Comment: Back Of Book. And no problem. Let $$f(x)=\frac{1}{5}(x-6), 2≤x≤3$$ The domain of $f^{-1}$ is the interval $[A,B]$ where $A=$SOLVE and $B=$SOLVE. Using your method I used the domain of $f$ and plugged it into both $A$ and $B$. The answers that I got were as follows: $A=f(x)=\frac{1}{5}(2-6)=\frac{-4}{5}$ and $B=f(x)=\frac{1}{5}(3-6)=\frac{-3}{5}$

Comment: Yes. And *their* answers are different?

Comment: This is the online problem. Unfortunately it doesn't tell me the correct answer. It only tells me that I am wrong.

Comment: There must be some  problem with the software!

Comment: Well thank you for your help. I'll attempt to see if anyone else is having the same problem then.